# Visual Studio 2022 - Visual Basic ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I've downloaded/installed Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition, but there is no way to find the ability to create a new ASP.NET Web Application (.Net Framework) using **Visual Basic**. It looks like I can only develop Windows Desktop Application using it.

Has it been deprecated? If not, how can I bring it back to life?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Run the Visual Studio installer.
Inside the .NET group, below the ".NET Framework 4.8 targeting pack", there is a component named **.NET Framework project and item templates** and make sure that you have installed it.

Visual Studio 2022 Installer - individual components .in NET group

Hovering over the component, the tooltip describes it as:

> Enables .NET Framework project templates, item templates & related
> features for .NET Framework development.

[image]

See: https://www.howtosolutions.net/2021/11/visual-studio-missing-asp-net-web-application-template-dotnet-framework/

Comment: Did not work. That item was already installed on mine and no way to build any .net core web apps in VB

Comment: Worked for me. I don't know why it's not selected by default when you have "ASP.NET and web development" selected in the workloads panel, as I'm pretty sure I didn't have to hunt this down in VS2019 and older versions.